# How to get 2nd or 3rd image of woocommerce product image gallary through a [shortcode] in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-gutenberg, wordpress-shortcode

I am using following code to view the first image of woo-commerce product images with the shortcode of [product_first_img]

```
function gal_first_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {

extract( shortcode_atts( array(
  'size' => ''
  ), $atts ) );

$image_size = 'medium';
if($size =! '') { $image_size = $size; }

$images = get_children(array(
    'post_parent' => get_the_ID(),
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'numberposts' => 1,
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'orderby' => 'menu_order',
    //'exclude' => get_post_thumbnail_id()
    )
);

if($images) {
    $gallery = '';
    foreach( $images as $image ) {
         $gallery .= wp_get_attachment_image($image->ID, $image_size);
    }
    $gallery .= '';
    return $gallery;
    }
}

add_shortcode('product_first_img', 'gal_first_shortcode');
```

Now, The problem is that I can get only the first image. What should I need to do if I want to get 2nd or thrid image through [shortcode]? I am not a developer. I will appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 0):

used the plugin of WP Bakery and it solved my issue.